# Dynamic lists in dynamics crm 2013 email templates

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I need to send an email notification on a workflow step, so it would look like this:

customer_name has 3 documents attached:

1) document1

2) document2

3) document3

All documents are stored in a grid in the customer entity.
My first thought was to create a hidden field and fill it with aggregation of documents in html format via plug-in/js (

```
<p>document1</p> <p>document2</p>.
```

...) and then load it with {aggregated_documents(customer)} into the template.

Is there any other way? Preferably without developing plug-ins and custom workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way of doing that without development.

Comment: So, witch way is more easonable?  Using hidden field, or   sending custom email with a custom workflow step?

Comment: I would suggest to use custom workflow activity approach. As for me it is the easiest way to implement.